wordpress theme with manifest.json forwards to wrong path
I'm trying to add my wordpress page to my home screen. By default, when I select 'add to home screen' on an iOS device, the bookmark saves the path "/wp-content/themes/... instead of "/".
I'm using react + pwa as my default theme in wordpress.
manifest.json:
{
  "short_name": "PWA Page",
  "name": "My PWA Page",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "favicon.ico",
      "sizes": "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
      "type": "image/x-icon"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo192.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo512.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "/",
  "scope": ".",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#ffffff",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}


I've tried to add "scope", however, that didn't change the url. Did I missed something?

What if you change start_url to "/"?

Unfortunately, that didn't help. I've updated the code after trying.
